# regex to find the data

Tags: regex

EDIT - I added all the last 50 texts, I saw that were sent from various people, unfortunately, it's not an automatic email...
list of all the text is [HERE](https://pastebin.com/10ypLXeS)

I'm struggling to find a matched pattern that will identify the needed items (date, start time, time zone) from this text:

```
1 April 20 16:00-16:30 Israel Time
Tomorrow, Wed Feb 12, 08:00-9:00 AM IST(IL)
Tomorrow, Wed Jan 22, 09:30-10:00 PM PST
11-May-20 19:00-20:30 Israel Time
```

The start time is an easy one: (\d+:\d+)- but I'm not sure what to be done with the other words and digits.

[image: examples of the current text, and needed values]

Comment: Is your examples exhaustive of all possible date formats? For example, could the date be “1 April”, “1 April 2020” or “April 1, 2020”? Your examples need to show all possible date formats and you should say that they do.

Comment: When “AM/PM” is present what use is capturing the time without capturing “AM/PM” as well, or converting 12-hour times to 24-hour format?

Comment: Hi all,
First, thanks for the response.
unfortunately, the ones who send this email are humans (LOL), that's why we got this variety. 
As per your question, I query 50 last emails and that was the output.

https://pastebin.com/10ypLXeS

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you provided, something like this would do it, with 3 captures as requested:

```
(\d+[-\s]\w+[-\s]\d+|\w+ \d+),?\s(\d+\:\d+)\-\d+\:\d+\s(?:AM\s|PM\s)?(.*)
```

[Online reference](https://regex101.com/r/7Fsd2w/1)

Comment: Don't ask me, I followed the specification provided by OP.